# How to Jump to a Bookmark in Word-VBA and insert text?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007

I am trying to create a Word document with a very simple word macro. The macro searches for a bookmark that I have placed in the text and then adds a date, 2 weeks into the future, at that location.

But when I create a new document from the template I keep getting bookmark not found. I have been through it loads of times and sometimes the bookmark is there, sometimes its there but not allowing you to click "Go to".

How can I get it to work? I have added a little piece of code to the `Document_New()` event but that keeps reporting *Bookmark not found*.

I have the document in a rar-file since my webserver can't handle .dotm extensions.
[Document](http://pafo.net/Garageplats.rar)

How can I make it so that when a new document is produced from this template, the new document has the date, 2 weeks ahead, placed between the 2 bold sections?

```
Sub Two_Weeks_Ahead()
''# Two_Weeks_Ahead Makro
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="TwoWeeks"
    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
        .ShowHidden = False
    End With

    Dim dt As Date
    dt = DateAdd("d", 14, DateTime.Now)

    Selection.TypeText Text:=Format(dt, "yyyy-MM-dd")
End Sub

Private Sub Document_New()
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="TwoWeeks"
    With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        .DefaultSorting = wdSortByName
        .ShowHidden = False
    End With

    Dim dt As Date
    dt = DateAdd("d", 14, DateTime.Now)

    Selection.TypeText Text:=Format(dt, "yyyy-MM-dd")
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you copy the code directly into your answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be because of the use of `ActiveDocument` in your code. The calling macro's document may still be the `ActiveDocument`, so it wouldn't find any bookmark. Here's how I would do it from a calling macro-enabled document/template which works well.

```
Sub AddTwoWeeks()
    Dim d As Document
    Set d = Documents.Add("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Title.dotx")

    Dim dt As Date
    dt = DateAdd("d", 14, DateTime.Now)

    Dim b As Bookmark
    Set b = d.Bookmarks("TwoWeeks")
    b.Range.Text = Format(dt, "yyyy-MM-dd")
End Sub
```